# Convert simple SelectMany into query syntax

Tags: c#, linq

The following is the simple form of `SelectMany()`. How if at all can we convert this into query syntax?

```
var array = new string[] { "Shaun", "Luttin" };
array
    .SelectMany(
        s => s
    );
```

The best that I can do produces the same output but introduces a new variable `c`...

```
var query = 
    from s in array.AsQueryable()
    from c in s
    select c;
```

...and results in the following fluent syntax.

```
array
   .SelectMany (
      s => s, 
      (s, c) => c
   );
```

**Re: Possible Duplication**

I have read the answers to [Is there a C# LINQ syntax for the Queryable.SelectMany() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414816/is-there-a-c-sharp-linq-syntax-for-the-queryable-selectmany-method) **I'm afraid the answers' translation's do not compile back to the original fluent syntax**.

Comment: Query expressions have a fluent equivalent. But not all fluent method calls have a query comprehension that they round trip with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler performs a translation to turn query syntax into method syntax. The details are specified in section 7.6.12 of the C# 5 spec. A quick search turns up only a couple translations that can result in a call to `SelectMany`, all in section 7.6.12.4:

> A query expression with a second from clause followed by a select clause:
>       from x1 in e1
>       from x2 in e2
>       select v
>   is translated into
>       `( e1 ) . SelectMany( x1 => e2 , ( x1 , x2 ) => v )`

and

> A query expression with a second from clause followed by something other than a select clause:
>   from x1 in e1
>   from x2 in e2
>   …
>   is translated into
>   `from * in ( e1 ) . SelectMany( x1 => e2 , ( x1 , x2 ) => new { x1 , x2 } )
>   …`

So there appears to be no translation that results in the other overload of `SelectMany` being called.

Comment: apparently if the `...` includes `group` without a following `from` that will prevent `SelectMany` from being called.