# How to chain methods in .net with async/await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, method-chaining

I've started to learn functional programming and while chaining methods looks great (in my opinion) in normal cases, it really gets ugly when dealing with async/await

```
await (await (await CosmosDbRepository<ApplicationProcess>
    .GetItemAsync(param.ProcessId))
.Historize(() => _analyseFinanciereService.ProcessAsync(), 
    ProcessStepEnum.Application))
.Notify(p => p.GetLastStep());
```

Is there any way to remove this noise?

Edit :

```
public static async Task<ApplicationProcess> Historize(
this ApplicationProcess process, 
Func<Task> fn, 
ProcessStepEnum stepEnum)
{
    var dateStart = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var error = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        await fn();
        return process;
    }
    …

public static async Task Notify<TResult>(
    this ApplicationProcess process, 
    Func<ApplicationProcess, TResult> fn)
...
```

Edit2 : with extensions methods accepting a Task

```
await CosmosDbRepository<ApplicationProcess>
    .GetItemAsync(param.ProcessId)
    .HistorizeAsync(() => _analyseFinanciereService.ProcessAsync(), ProcessStepEnum.Application)
    .NotifyAsync(p => p.GetLastStep());
```

So that's what I was looking for even if I'm confused with the latest comments

Comment: You don't. *Don't* chain the methods if one needs the results of another. Or convert them to extension methods that accept `Task<Whatever>` as their first member

Comment: I would use [Facade Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) usually for this purposes!

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos that's what I did, maybe not the way I was supposed to? I've edited the original post to show the actual signature of the chained methods

Comment: @XavSc first of all, it's *await* that chains the actual async method with the continuation - whatever comes after it. Second, the extension method should be `Historize(
this Task<ApplicationProcess>` process, ...)` to allow direct chaining. *Each* such method would have to use `await  process` to get the actual process object though. What do you expect to gain by chaining methods like this though? What does `fn` do, does it depend on `process`? If you want to create pipelines of processing steps, use the Dataflow library

Comment: @XavSc chaining methods like this won't improve code readability, quite the opposite. It won't create a pipeline either, it's just a series of async calls. By creating a real pipeline with Dataflow blocks you real steps with input/output buffering, backpressure, configurable parallelism for steps.

Comment: is it this lib? : www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.

Comment: why do you say it won't improve readability? aside from syntactic noise I think it does

Comment: You could use Rx https://github.com/dotnet/reactive

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What would Rx allow me to do in that context?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*All the code presented I uploaded as a [LinqPad query](http://share.linqpad.net/omi2uh.linq), so You can try it right away.*

Functional programming has a concept of [monad](https://ericlippert.com/category/monads/) (unfamiliar C# programmers I strongly recommend to start with the link provided). A C# task may be considered a monad, and as far as I understand it is exactly what You need.

For the purpose of this answer I made a simplified example of what You have:

```
await (await (await A.GetNumber()).DoubleIt()).SquareIt()
```

where the methods are as follows (defined as static just for my convenience):

```
public static class A
{
    public static Task<int> GetNumber(){return Task.FromResult(3);}
    public static Task<int> DoubleIt(this int input){return Task.FromResult(2 * input);}
    public static Task<int> SquareIt(this int input){return Task.FromResult(input * input);}
}
```

Now You can easily chain them with just a bit of glue which can look like this:

```
public static async Task<TOut> AndThen<TIn, TOut>(this Task<TIn> inputTask, Func<TIn, Task<TOut>> mapping)
{
    var input = await inputTask;
    return (await mapping(input));
}
```

The `AndThen` method acts exactly like a monadic bind:

```
await A
     .GetNumber()
     .AndThen(A.DoubleIt)
     .AndThen(A.SquareIt)
```

What's more important, C# has nice syntax for working with monads: the LINQ query comprehension syntax. You just need to define a SelectMany method which works with the type You desire (Task in this case) and You're ready to go.

Below I implemented the most "hardcore"  overload of SelectMany (with additional `resultSelector`)  which gives You the most flexibility. The simple version would be almost exactly the same as `AndThen` (I think just renaming would do the job).

```
public static async Task<TOut> SelectMany<TIn, TInterm, TOut>(
   this Task<TIn> inputTask,
   Func<TIn, Task<TInterm>> mapping,
   Func<TIn, TInterm, TOut> resultSelector)
{
    var input = await inputTask;
    return resultSelector(input, await mapping(input));
}
```

With it You can use the syntax:

```
var task = 
    from num in A.GetNumber()
    from doubled in num.DoubleIt()
    from squared in num.SquareIt()
    select $"number: {num} doubled: {doubled}, squared: {squared}";
    
Console.WriteLine(await task);
```

And You get `number: 3 doubled: 6, squared: 9`.

The simple SelectMany version would allow You to use `squared` as the only possible expression in the final `select` line. The "hardcore" version lets You use any expression that uses any of the values defined after a `from` keyword.

Comment: interesting, I fail to understand where you call your custom SelectMany though

Comment: The query comprehension syntax presented here gets compiled to series of calls of SelectMany. You can read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29639502/1865984 or https://dzone.com/articles/selectmany-probably-the-most-p

Comment: I added a ` bool continueOnCapturedContext = false` as a last parameter to your AndThen method, passing it into a ConfigureAwait on each line. Plus unnecessary parenthesis on your return line?

Comment: Where place I put  `.ConfigureAwait(false)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement it in a way that - only when the source task successfully completes( Without faults), it should go ahead and execute the next. This seems to be working fine but trying to thing to think in any case this could fail:-

```
return await await sourceTask.ContinueWith(async st => 
            {
               var res = await st; //
               return await contWith(res);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted & TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion;
```