# Linq to XML conditioning attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is my xml

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bnr.ro/xsd nbrfxrates.xsd">
    <Header>
        <Publisher>National Bank of Romania</Publisher>
        <PublishingDate>2016-03-24</PublishingDate>
    <MessageType>DR</MessageType>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Subject>Reference rates</Subject>
        <OrigCurrency>RON</OrigCurrency>
        <Cube date="2016-03-24">            
            <Rate currency="EUR">4.4655</Rate>          
        </Cube>
        <Cube date="2016-03-23">                
            Rate currency="EUR">4.4641</Rate>               
        </Cube>
    </Body>
</DataSet>
```

I want to verify the **Cube** Attribute **date** to receive the EUR value from yesterday date.

For example if today is 2016-03-24 I want to receive the value **4.4641** from 2016-03-23.

I tried with LINQ to XML

```
    string date_yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
XElement root = XElement.Parse(sbXmlText.ToString());
                IEnumerable<XElement> adress =
                    from el in root.Descendants("Cube")
                    let z = el.ElementsAfterSelf().FirstOrDefault()
                    where z != null && (string)el.Attribute("date") == date_yesterday
                    select el;
                foreach (XElement el in adress)
                    Console.WriteLine(el);
```

And tried

```
string date_yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

             XElement root = XElement.Parse(sbXmlText.ToString());
             IEnumerable<XElement> adress =
                 root.Descendants("Cube").Where(r => r.Attribute("date").Value == date_yesterday);                    
             foreach (XElement el in adress)
                 Console.WriteLine(el);
```

And it returns everytime null

Comment: Can't you just copy-paste the XML, instead of posting a picture of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML has *default namespace*. You can use *"`XNamespace`+element's local-name*" to reference element in namespace, for example :

```
var xml = @"<DataSet xmlns='http://www.bnr.ro/xsd' 
xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
 xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.bnr.ro/xsd nbrfxrates.xsd'>
    <Header>
        <Publisher>National Bank of Romania</Publisher>
        <PublishingDate>2016-03-24</PublishingDate>
    <MessageType>DR</MessageType>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Subject>Reference rates</Subject>
        <OrigCurrency>RON</OrigCurrency>
        <Cube date='2016-03-24'>            
            <Rate currency='IDR'>1.1111</Rate>
            <Rate currency='EUR'>4.4655</Rate>          
        </Cube>
        <Cube date='2016-03-23'>                
            <Rate currency='EUR'>4.4641</Rate>               
        </Cube>
    </Body>
</DataSet>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

//XNamespace that reference default namespace URI:
XNamespace d = "http://www.bnr.ro/xsd";

var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;

//Use `XNamespace+element's local-name` to reference element in namespace:
var result = (from cube in doc.Descendants(d+"Cube")
              from rate in cube.Elements(d+"Rate")
              where 
                ((DateTime)cube.Attribute("date")).Date == yesterday
                    && 
                (string)rate.Attribute("currency") == "EUR"
              select (decimal)rate
              ).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**output :**

```
4.4641
```

Comment: Thank you . And I have another question. If I have two tags with Rate and I want the one where currency = "EUR" I will write in select clause an equal condition ?

Comment: @RalucaIonescu you can use LINQ `SelectMany()` construct (which translates to [double `from` clause in query syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414816/is-there-a-c-sharp-linq-syntax-for-the-queryable-selectmany-method)) and add the currency filter in the `where` clause. See the updated answer